# How to input .apk file and read classes and xml file from the input apk file in eclipse?

Tags: android

Program should be like input the apk file then it should extract all the java and xml document and from that i need to read the required content from the java and xml document.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Decompile".

You can try google searching "[Android apk decompile](https://www.google.com/search?q=Android%20apk%20decompile&rlz=1C1LENN_enUS520US520&oq=Android%20apk%20decompile&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i59j0j69i60j0j69i62.180j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)."

One popular tool to do this is [APKTool](http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/).

Comment: There are other tools which may do some of things you want to accomplish. You'll have to search though.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the code for any android app. 
But decompiled code wont be the same as the code before. It will be harder to understand.

You can check this video [tutorial..](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tioug10tuo)